# xcode dos view_controller moverse entre ellos

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode, swift3

Buenas estoy haciendo la prueba de tener dos `view_controller` uno llamado `Main` y otro `view_2`, en cada uno hay un botón y que sirve de navegación entre ellos, pero me falla el volver.

En el primer `view controller`, llamado `main` tengo este código :

```
@IBAction func button_1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let ViewControllerDos = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view_2")
    self.presentViewController(ViewControllerDos, animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```

Y en segundo `view controller`, llamado `view_2` tengo esto :

```
@IBAction func button_2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard1 : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "view_2", bundle: nil)
    let ViewControllerDos1 = storyBoard1.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main")
    self.presentViewController(ViewControllerDos1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Pero me da error al pulsar el boton en el segundo ¿que estoy haciendo mal?.

Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el log del error?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no entiendes cuál es el flujo, por eso desaconsejo enormemente cuando se empieza utilizar `Storyboards` ya que no hacen más que entorpecer el aprendizaje.

Fíjate que en el primero haces un `presentViewController` y por tanto lo que está haciendo es mostrar un `ViewController` de forma modal. 
Bien, para volver hacia atrás lo que debes hacer es cerrar ese `ViewController` utilizando la siguiente función:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Con esto, al estar presentado de forma modal, se cerrará y volverás al `ViewController` que lo presentó.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es que he encontrado muchos manuales de swift y de como trabajar con el pero no soy capaz de encontrar nada que me explique estas cosas básicas, supongo que por que se dan por entendidas.